# Crystal Reports Optional Group Header

Tags: crystal-reports

Folks - I have a Group Header break on TYPE.
Possible values are SALES and PURCHASES

Requirement is to always display TYPE at the top of every page.
However if mid page, TYPE changes, I need to display the new TYPE.

Further complicating, this is a sub-report.

Currently, I display TYPE on the top of every page.
But not sure how to conditionally display TYPE midpage.

If for example there is only one TYPE in the report:
- Should always display at the top of the page, regardless of page count:

If all the transactions on page one are SALES, but page two start PURCHASES
(Last row on page one is SALES, 1st row on page two is PURCHASES)
- Page two should display PURCHASES at the top of the page only

So it seems the formula driving midpage has to consider:
- last row on the page prior

Suggestions?

Comment: I can apply suppress to the header (RowNumber = 1) but, if on say page 7, a new TYPE starts up , I'll get a double message.

Comment: is the group inside the sub report??

Comment: Yes Sir - inside of a subreport. I have hacked GH1 to display headings on every page, and print the TYPE.  GH2 is the "real" header responsible for grouping of TYPE.